# Global Variable in JavaScript , variables defined without var

Tags: javascript

The function below will return `b is not defined` because the compiler will look in the function and then into the global scope in search for a variable `b`.

However, I assumed that defining b without the word `var` would automatically create a global variable?

Can anyone explain the rules when omitting the word `var`?

```
function foo(a) {    
  console.log( a + b );    
  b = a;
}

foo( 2 );
```

Comment: it is because  of `console.log` there b is not defined.

Comment: it does, yes but you're trying to use the variable `b` before you've defined it, of you move the console.log to after `b=a;` it will return 4

Answer (score 4):

Not using `var` in a function for a variable declaration does make it global, but in your case, the JavaScript engine is hitting this line:

```
console.log( a + b );
```

before it hits this line:

```
b = a;
```

And, that's the line that declares it (globally).

And, because you didn't use `var`, the declaration is not hoisted to the top of the code base (which it would have been with `var` - you would still not have gotten a value for `b` because only the declaration would be hoisted, not the initialization, but it would not have thrown an error), so you get your error.

See more about `var` and hoisting **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)**.

Answer (score 1):

In strict mode:

- Using an undeclared variable will throw an exception

In non-strict mode:

- Assigning to an undeclared variable will create a global, but this is **not** hoisted

  - Declaring a variable with `var` creates a local variable and **is** hoisted to the top of the function
- Reading an undeclared variable will throw an exception

---

Since you are not in strict mode and you try to read `b` **before** you assign a value to it, you get an exception.

---

Guidelines to follow:

- Always `"use strict"`
- Always declare your variables
- Declare them in the global scope if you want them there
- … but try to avoid global scope. Consider using a closure instead if you think a global would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared this way `b = a` are not hoisted, like variables declared with the `var` keyword. That means that, at runtime, the compiler reads b, not as undefined (as would happen with `var b = a`), but as something that doesn´t exist at all, thus throwing a ReferenceError.

Info on Hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting